# How to align grid row items with CSS if empty cell exist

Tags: html, css

For example, I have 5 photos which I want to place into 3 columns - this means that we have 3x2 grid. 3 items are in the first row, 2 items in the second row. After this positioning, I have one cell empty left. I want to adjust items per center that there no empty space in the right left.

Things to mention:

- Columns are adjustable and entered by user, so it's should be dynamic and don't work specifically with 3
- For instance, if I have 6 photos, there would be all places filled which is ok
- I already found some solutions on SO, but those solutions were for one specific case which I can't adapt for my problem

Here is the code:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col">
    <img style="width: 100%;height: 100%" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100" class="gallery__img" src="https://cpmr-islands.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/07/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img style="width: 100%;height: 100%" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100" class="gallery__img" src="https://cpmr-islands.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/07/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img style="width: 100%;height: 100%" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100" class="gallery__img" src="https://cpmr-islands.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/07/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img style="width: 100%;height: 100%" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100" class="gallery__img" src="https://cpmr-islands.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/07/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img style="width: 100%;height: 100%" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100" class="gallery__img" src="https://cpmr-islands.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/07/test.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

My desired solution with 3 columns and all spaces filled:
[image]

3 columns and one space left:
[image]

Comment: I could achieve this using `flex` display, I tried it and it works, for different number of columns, you would use javascript whether you use `flex` or `grid` display if the number of columns are specified by the user, if you want `flex` implementation of the solution, I will post an answer.

Comment: So what is your desired result? You want the second row of images to be centered?

Comment: @Abdelrahman would be great to see your solution.

Comment: @BrettDonald I've edited my post with the desired solution.

Comment: @BrettDonald I added the solution with `flex` display, you can try change the number of columns through the input field in the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS and without javascript you would need to use some sort of pseudo selector approach to target the orphan image

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --main-bg-color: pink;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #87480f;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #c26f25 0%, #87480f 100%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 20px;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: start;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100%, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: max-content;
}

.grid-item {
  position: relative;
}

.grid-item:last-child {
  grid-column: auto;
}

img {
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(69, 47, 27, 0.8);
}

.grid-item:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5px;
  left: -1.5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 16px;
  z-index: -1;;
  background-color: rgba(247, 231, 215, 0.25);
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 4px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    --img-width: calc((100% - 40px) / 2);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(var(--img-width), 1fr));
  }

  .grid-item:last-child {
    grid-column: span 2;
  }

}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    --img-width: calc((100% - 40px) / 3);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(var(--img-width), 1fr));
  }

  .grid-item:last-child {
    grid-column: span 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="grid-item">
        <img src='https://unsplash.it/1024/683?image=102';/>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <img src='https://unsplash.it/1024/683?image=110';/>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <img src='https://unsplash.it/1024/683?image=112';/>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <img src='https://unsplash.it/1024/683?image=132';/>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <img src='https://unsplash.it/1024/683?image=35';/>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <img src='https://unsplash.it/1024/683?image=289';/>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item">
        <img src='https://unsplash.it/1024/683?image=184';/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex` instead of `display: grid`, and have a fixed width for the divs inside the container, so that when it contains more than 3 divs in a row, it wraps to the next column.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  max-width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">
      <img style="width: 100%;height: 100%" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100" class="gallery__img" src="https://cpmr-islands.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/07/test.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img style="width: 100%;height: 100%" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100" class="gallery__img" src="https://cpmr-islands.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/07/test.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img style="width: 100%;height: 100%" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100" class="gallery__img" src="https://cpmr-islands.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/07/test.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img style="width: 100%;height: 100%" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100" class="gallery__img" src="https://cpmr-islands.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/07/test.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <img style="width: 100%;height: 100%" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100" class="gallery__img" src="https://cpmr-islands.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/07/test.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution using `flex` as requested. You can change number of columns through the input fild.

**Notes:**

- You can set a gap with max 1%, otherwise, the gap may make the content to wrap for the next line. If you want to set a higher gap, make account for it in your `width` value in the javascript, try using `calc` .e.g. `width = "calc( 33% - 10px)"` where 10px is your gap value.
- The added css `max-height` and `max-width` for styling images is just to make sure the images don't get too big for small number of colums .e.g. `1` or `2` as width for most devices are bigger than height. Having `.col` div with height equal to the `width` when the width is `100%` of the viewport, will make the image too big for the screen, you can remove them or adjust them as you like, but if you want them **circular**, make sure both `max-height` and `max-width` have the same values.

  ```
  .img-style {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      max-height: 400px;
      max-width: 400px;
  }
  ```

- The `flex` display for `.col` class is just to center the image inside the `div`.

```js
document.querySelector(".input-group").addEventListener("submit", changeNumOfCols);

function changeNumOfCols(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const nums = document.querySelector("#cols_input").value;
  const cols = document.querySelectorAll('.col');

  cols.forEach((col) => {
    console.log(col);
    col.style.width = parseInt((100 / nums) - 1) + '%';
  });
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1%;
}

.col {
  width: 32%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-group {
  margin: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img-style {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<form class="input-group">
  <input id="cols_input" type="number" placeholder="number of columns" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col">
    <img class="img-style" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100" class="gallery__img" src="https://cpmr-islands.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/07/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img class="img-style" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100" class="gallery__img" src="https://cpmr-islands.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/07/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img class="img-style" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100" class="gallery__img" src="https://cpmr-islands.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/07/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img class="img-style" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100" class="gallery__img" src="https://cpmr-islands.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/07/test.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img class="img-style" loading="lazy" width="100" height="100" class="gallery__img" src="https://cpmr-islands.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2019/07/test.png">
  </div>
</div>
```